# Asp.net Core Import Excel File FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, epplus

I've had this working but it has stopped and I can't figure out why. I'm importing a simple excel file, using EPPlus.Core v1.3. Here's the code I'm using:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Import(IFormFile file)
    {
        //Get file
        var newfile = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
        var fileExtension = newfile.Extension;

        //Check if file is an Excel File
        if (fileExtension.Contains(".xls"))
        {
            //Create an excel package
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newfile))
            {
                //Get the first worksheet in the file
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
...
```

The var worksheet line throws an error

> "IndexOutOfRangeException: Worksheet position out of range."

However, when I look at the package variable I see this error

> "Length = 'package.File.Length' threw an exception of type
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'"

What am I missing here? Like I said, this used to work and I can't think of anything I changed related to this code to cause this issue.

Comment: To me it looks like you are taking an uploaded file, take the filename via a `FileInfo` object and then you pass the `FileInfo`-instance to `ExcelPackage`. You should probably save the file to a folder somewhere before trying to load open it.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid saving to the server if I don't have to. The files are quite small so my hope was to just load them to memory and process.

Comment: Well then you need to pass a stream to `ExcelPackage` instead of a FileInfo. `new ExcelPackage(file.OpenReadStream())` might do it though I haven't looked at `IFormFile` for a few versions so the name might differ. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same file also? It looks like the file might not have two worksheets and since the index is 1, it is looking for the second worksheet.

Comment: It is the same file and I have tried package.Workbook.Worksheets.First() and Worksheets[0] as well. Neither work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the file in a `MemoryStream` and create a `ExcelPackage` from there.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(FileUpload1.FileBytes))
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(ms))
{
    //work with the excel document
}
```

`FileUpload1.FileBytes` if for asp.net webforms, but I'm guessing Core has something similar.